# Conditional Value Assignment in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

In the following the sample data:

```
keyword <- c("advertising plan","advertising budget",
         "marketing plan",
         "marketing budget",
         "hr plan",
         "hr budget",
         "operation plan",
         "operation budget")
indicator <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1)
df <- cbind(keyword,indicator)
```

I need to create a new variable "**`Topic`**". I will assign the text "`Advertising`" to the cell if the keyword is "`advertising plan`" and "`advertising budget`"; "`Marketing`" to the cell if the keyword is "`marketing plan`" and "`marketing budget`".

I tried to use the

`df$Topic[which(df$keyword == c("advertising plan","advertising budget") <- "Advertising"`.

But it did not work out. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
#Convert to dataframe if it isn't already
df = as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#Extract first word of the keyword as the topic
df$Topic = sapply(strsplit(df$keyword," "),function(x) x[1])
#Set all values other than marketing and advertising to blank (or NA if you want)
df$Topic[df$Topic != "marketing" & df$Topic != "advertising"] = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keyword <- c("advertising plan","advertising budget",
             "marketing plan",
             "marketing budget",
             "hr plan",
             "hr budget",
             "operation plan",
             "operation budget")
indicator <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(keyword, indicator, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[df$keyword %in% c("advertising plan", "advertising budget"), "Topic"] = "Advertising"
df[df$keyword %in% c("marketing plan", "marketing budget"), "Topic"] = "Marketing"
```

or, more flexible approach:

```
df[grepl("advertising plan|advertising budget", df$keyword), "Topic"] = "Advertising"
df[grepl("marketing plan|marketing budget", df$keyword), "Topic"] = "Marketing"
```